# ModX AjaxSearch - each search result in a separate single <div class="well">

Tags: html, modx

I have ModX AjaxSearch installed (EVOLUTION) and works great. However, I want my search results in separate  boxes, and the best I can do is to get ALL search results in 1 box. Question is how to get them all separated into different single "wells"??? The rest of my site has masonry layout with 3 column-rows and I want my search-results to show exactly the same as that.

My search-results template:

```
<div id="content">
        {{project_template_search-results-masonry}}
```

Code for my search results masonry:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="articles">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="well">
                    [*content*]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can customise the result TPL?

```
[[AjaxSearch? 
&language=`english` 
&showInputForm=`0` 
&ajaxSearch=`0` 
&tplResult=`search-result` 
&showMoreResults=`1` 
&ajaxMax=`50` 
&highlightResult=`1`
]]
```

This below modify to your needs.

```
<div class="ajax_search_box" onclick="window.location.href='[+as.resultLink+]'">
  <a href="[+as.resultLink+]" title="[+as.pagetitle+]">[+as.pagetitle+]</a><br />
  <em>[+as.extract:is=``:then=``:else=`[+as.extract+]`+]</em>
</div>

<hr class="hr" />
```